# Amadeus Flight Availabilities in Python - Error 400

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, amadeus

I am trying to use the POST method of Amadeus flight availabilities API on Python, but is is still giving me error 400. Any suggestions? Many thanks.

```
from amadeus import Client, ResponseError, Location
import requests

amadeus = Client(
client_id='My ID',
client_secret='My Secret')

try:
    flights = amadeus.get('/v2/shopping/flight-offers',originLocationCode = "GIG",destinationLocationCode = "ATL",departureDate = "2023-01-31",nonStop = "true",travelClass = "BUSINESS",adults = 1)
    body = flights.data[0]
    print(body)
except ResponseError as error:
    print(error)
   
try:
    availability = amadeus.post('/v1/shopping/availability/flight-availabilities', body)
    print(availability.result)
except ResponseError as error:
    print('headers: ', error.response.request.headers)
    print('body: ', error.response.request.params)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [their API documentation](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-availabilities-search/api-reference), the body of the second API call needs to be in the following format:

```
{
  "originDestinations": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "originLocationCode": "BOS",
      "destinationLocationCode": "MAD",
      "departureDateTime": {
        "date": "2021-11-14",
        "time": "21:15:00"
      }
    }
  ],
  "travelers": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "travelerType": "ADULT"
    }
  ],
  "sources": [
    "GDS"
  ]
}
```

Right now you are just feeding the second call the return from the first, which doesn't seem to be what they're looking for.

You might also need to feed the proper headers, something like:

```
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

then you would do

```
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=body)
```